# Checked check box value on load

Tags: angular, angular8

The checkbox value need to be selected/checked by default. Tried following ways which was not working.

html

```
 <form [formGroup]="form">
 <label><input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" [(ngModel)]="organism.active" formControlName="active" >Selected</label>
</form>
```

ts

```
constructor() { this.getFromGroup(); }
 private getFromGroup() {
    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
        'active': new FormControl(true),
    })

  }
```

even tried this

```
 this.form.patchValue({
      'active': true
    })
```

Comment: Please add specific Angular version tags only if your question is specific to that version. Following that logic, it doesn't make sense to tag a question with two different versions of Angular, since you are unlikely to be mixing two in the same application.

Comment: Thanks, corrected now.

Answer (score 1):

Set your ngmodel value to true in your typescript code. It should work. 
`[(ngModel)]="organism_active"` 
 In your ts code,

```
this.organism_active = true;
```

OR Try this code:

```
 <form [formGroup]="form">
          <small class="text-muted">Test Value</small>
          <input type="checkbox" id="organism_active" name="organism_active" class="form-control checker" formControlName="organism_active" checked>

 </form>


   this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      organism_active: [true]
    });
```

Comment: template driven option worked. Why reactive was not working ? . Is it because I'm mixing both ? using ngModel & formControl..

Answer (score 0):

Just add a attribute to input `checked="checked"` it will work

Answer (score 0):

You're using `ngModel` for a reactive form which is not right

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" formControlName="active"> Selected
    </label>
</form>
```

If you want to initalize the form value with the data you can use the below code

```
this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
        'active': new FormControl(this.organism.active),
})
```

Comment: No its not selected, I'm using both ngModel & formControl

Comment: can you create a stackblitz to reproduce it please?